# What is the optimal way to create a graph with add_edge_list() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx, graph-tool

I am trying to create large graph via `graph-tool` library (near 10^6 - 10^7 vertices) and fill vertex property with vertex name or use names instead of vertex indexes. I have:

1. list of names:

   ```
   ['50', '56', '568']
   ```
2. set of edges, but instead of vertex indexes it consists of their names:

   ```
   edge_list = {frozenset({'568', '56'}), frozenset({'56', '50'}), frozenset({'50', '568'})}
   ```

Since `add_edge_list()` allows to create vertices if they are no such vertix in the graph. I'm trying to use it to fill an empty graph. It works ok, but when I was trying to get vertex by its name, I got an error that there are no vertex with such index.

Here is the code of my program:

```py
g = grt.Graph(directed=False)
edge_list = {frozenset({'568', '56'}), frozenset({'56', '50'}), frozenset({'50', '568'})}
ids = ['50', '56', '568']
g.add_edge_list(edge_list, hashed=True, string_vals=True)
print(g.vertex('50'))
```

The error message of `print(g.vertex('50'))`:

```
ValueError: Invalid vertex index: 50
```

I want to create graph:

1. Using `edge_list` only;
2. Having quick access to a vertex by its name;
3. Optimal by time (and RAM if possible).

Is there any good way to do this?

EDIT: 
Current code:

```py
g = grt.Graph(directed=False)
g.add_vertex(len(ids))
vprop = g.new_vertex_property("string", vals=ids)
g.vp.user_id = vprop  
for vert1, vert2 in edges_list:
    g.add_edge(g.vertex(ids_dict[vert1]), g.vertex(ids_dict[vert2]))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a dense graph with 10^6 - 10^7 vertices *(Is it some medical data or social graph? It can change everything)*, you shouldn't use `networkx` because it is written on pure Python so it is ~10-100 times slower than `graph-tool` or `igraph`. In your case I recommend you to use `graph-tool`. It is the fastest (~as `igraph`) Python graph processing library.

`graph-tool` behaviour differs from `networkx`. When you create the `networkx` node, its identifier is what you wrote in node constructor so you can get the node by its ID. In graph-tool every vertex ID is the integer from 1 to GRAPH_SIZE:

> Each vertex in a graph has an unique index, which is always between 0 and N−1, where N is the number of vertices. This index can be obtained by using the vertex_index attribute of the graph (which is a property map, see Property maps), or by converting the vertex descriptor to an int.

Every additional information about graph, vertices or edges is stored in [property maps](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/graph_tool.html#graph_tool.PropertyMap). And when you are using `.add_edge_list()` with `hashed=True`, the new property map is returned as the result of `.add_edge_list()`. So in your case you should handle your vertices like this:

```
# Create graph
g = grt.Graph(directed=False)

# Create edge list
# Why frozensets? You don't really need them. You can use ordinary sets or tuples
edge_list = {
    frozenset({'568', '56'}),
    frozenset({'56', '50'}),
    frozenset({'50', '568'})
}

# Write returned PropertyMap to a variable!
vertex_ids = g.add_edge_list(edge_list, hashed=True, string_vals=True)

g.vertex(1)

Out [...]: <Vertex object with index '1' at 0x7f3b5edde4b0>

vertex_ids[1]

Out [...]: '56'
```

If you want to get a vertex according to the ID, you should construct mapping dict manually (well, I am not a `graph-tool` guru, but I can't find simple solution):

`very_important_mapping_dict = {vertex_ids[i]: i for i in range(g.num_vertices())}`

So you can easily get a vertex index:

```
very_important_mapping_dict['568']

Out [...]: 0

vertex_ids[0]

Out [...]: '568'
```

Comment: Yes, it is a social graph actually. Will it help some way? 
I am using `igraph` for clustering (or searching communities if you prefer this term) and `graph-tool` for measuring centralities and for drawing graphs.
I am using frozenset to collect data from the source.

Runtime is the main problem. The question is: what will be faster: using `add_edge_lis()` or `add_edge()` in cycle? I added current code in the question field above.